# I'm using gowong/material-sheet-fab but it's showing me errors .Can anyone help me out?

Tags: android

Here is my Fab Activity

```
public class Fab extends FloatingActionButton implements AnimatedFab {

public Fab(Context context) {
    super(context);
}


@Override
public void show() {
    show(0, 0);
}
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public void show(float translationX, float translationY) {

    setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

/**
 * Hides the FAB.
 */
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public void hide() {

    setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

}

Here is my Main Activity

```
 // MATERIAL ANIMATED FAB
    Fab fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    View sheetView = findViewById(R.id.fab_sheet);
    View overlay = findViewById(R.id.overlay);
    int sheetColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.fab_sheet_color);
    int fabColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.fab_color);

    // Initialize material sheet FAB
    materialSheetFab = new MaterialSheetFab<>(fab, sheetView, overlay,
            sheetColor, fabColor);
    materialSheetFab.setEventListener(new MaterialSheetFabEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShowSheet() {
            // Called when the material sheet's "show" animation starts.

        }

        @Override
        public void onSheetShown() {
            // Called when the material sheet's "show" animation ends.

        }

        @Override
        public void onHideSheet() {
            // Called when the material sheet's "hide" animation starts.
        }

        public void onSheetHidden() {
            // Called when the material sheet's "hide" animation ends.
        }
    });
```

Here is my logcat

> Process: com.teepe.teepe, PID: 29259
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.teepe.teepe/com.teepe.teepe.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to com.teepe.teepe.Fab
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to com.teepe.teepe.Fab
>           at com.teepe.teepe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:95)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: Please show your XML file so we can have a look into this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to com.teepe.teepe.Fab at com.teepe.teepe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:95)`, in your `MainActivity`, check this [line](https://github.com/gowong/material-sheet-fab/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml#L44) of code from the library you used:

```
<com.gordonwong.materialsheetfab.sample.Fab
       android:id="@+id/fab"
       style="@style/Widget.MaterialSheetFab.Fab"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Change your `<path.to.your.FloatingActionButton` to `<path.to.your.Fab` in the layout of `MainActivity` (preferably, `activity_main.xml`) in which your `R.id.fab` has been declared.

Hope this should fix your error. Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in if it does.

Comment: Yes I corrected it this error is gone but now it showing another error    Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.teepe.teepe/com.teepe.teepe.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #90: Error inflating class com.teepe.teepe.Fab

Comment: See this closed issue with this same error on that same library you've implemented: https://github.com/gowong/material-sheet-fab/issues/19